# Evaluate fourier coefficient of $f(t)=t$.

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis

> Evaluate the Fourier coefficient of $f(t)=t$.

$$\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} te^{-int}dt$$

I'd be glad for help with this calculation. My integration skills need an improvement.

**My Try: (following the hint)**
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} te^{-int}dt = \frac{te^{-int}}{-in}|_0^{2\pi} - \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{-int}}{-in} = \frac{2\pi e^{-2\pi in}}{-ni} - \frac{e^{-int}}{-n^2}|_0^{2\pi} \\= \frac{2\pi e^{-2\pi in}}{-ni} - \left( \frac{e^{-2\pi in}}{-n^2}- \frac{e^0}{-n^2}  \right)$$

Am I on the right path?

Comment: Integrate by parts to kill $t$, then you have a simple exponential integral.

Comment: Or you can calculate $a_0/2$ which does the same job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** Integrate it by parts

$$\int_0^{2\pi} te^{-int}\, dt={i\over n}\left(te^{-int}\bigg|_0^{2\pi} - \int_0^{2\pi}e^{-int}\, dt\right)$$

Comment: You have some small typos, the RHS is a function of $t$ the way you have written it, and the second integral should have the inner function as just the indefinite primitive, not the definite number, that's tantamount to claiming $\int_a^b(f\cdot g)=\int_a^bf\cdot\int_a^b g$ which is not (in general) true.

Comment: @AdamHughes Please fix this for me. Thanks. :)

Comment: Where do my calculations go wrong?

Comment: There you go this time, but in general you want to fix your own mistakes, since you should be able to edit by now.

Comment: @AlonAlon use the fact that $e^{2\pi i n}=e^0=1$.

Comment: @AdamHughes Yes. I was (and am) stuck on another problem. Thank you.

Comment: But then I get $-\frac{1}{ni}$.. Why?

Comment: Note $i^4=1$, so $\frac{-1}{ni}=\frac{-i^4}{ni}=\frac{-i^3}{n}=\frac{-i(i^2)}{n}=\frac{i}{n}$

Answer (score 1):

Take
\begin{alignat}{2}
u&=t &\qquad dv&=e^{-int}\,dt\\
du&=dt &\qquad v&={e^{-int}\over -in}.
\end{alignat}
Integrating by parts and simplifying you get
\begin{align}
{1\over 2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}te^{-int}\,dt&={1\over 2\pi}\left[-{te^{-int}\over in}\Bigg|_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}-\int_0^{2\pi}{e^{-int}\over -in}\,dt\right]\\
&={1\over 2\pi}\left[-{te^{-int}\over in}+{e^{-int}\over n^2}\right]_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}\\
&={i\over n}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. I think the answer is $\frac{i(-1)^n}{n}$.

Comment: My integration checks out in *Mathematica*.

Comment: That's weird. I've taken it from a book..

Comment: Books are fallible. (*Mathematica* is too but this is a straightforward calculation.)